How to stop go router from loading twice?
I am new to flutter and want to use GoFlutter for nested navigation. When I start the app the router will load twice. I am not sure why this happens.
Flutter go_router version: ^14.6.0
Logs

I've tried to remove the initialLocation parmater but it still happens. I've also disabled the ChangeNotifierProvider which managed the light and dark theme. But still double rendering happens.
main.dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Register to supabase
  await Supabase.initialize(
    url: "XXX",
    anonKey: "XXX",);

  runApp(const App());
  // runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
  //   create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
  //   child: const App(),
  // ));
}

app.dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      // General information
      title: "Construction Diary",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: RouteConfig.returnRouter(),
      // Theme management
      theme: lightMode,
      darkTheme: darkMode,
      // themeMode: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeMode,
    );
  }
}


route_config.dart
final _rootNavigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class RouteConfig {
  static GoRouter returnRouter() {
    return GoRouter(
      navigatorKey: _rootNavigationKey,
      initialLocation: "/projects",
      debugLogDiagnostics: true,
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: '/login',
          name: RouteNames.login,
          builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
        ),
        StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
          builder: (context, state, navigationShell) => LayoutScaffold(
            navigationShell: navigationShell,
          ),
          branches: [
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  name: RouteNames.projects,
                  path: '/projects',
                  builder: (context, state) => const ProjectOverview(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            StatefulShellBranch(
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                  name: RouteNames.settings,
                  path: '/settings',
                  builder: (context, state) => const SettingsOverview(),
                ),
                GoRoute(
                  name: RouteNames.profile,
                  path: '/profile',
                  builder: (context, state) => const ProfileOverview(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


I believe is a misconception of whats going on in your build method, to me it seems that its not goRouter but your build method that runs twice, maybe because you're in flutter web and when the view change size (for example when opening the right inspector) it needs to recompute the UI.
One way to avoid and test it is yo use an StatefulWidget and create the go router in initState, that way when the UI refreshes the go router will use the previous initialized variable
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App>createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
late final GoRouter router;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  router = RouteConfig.returnRouter();
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      // General information
      title: "Construction Diary",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: router,
      // Theme management
      theme: lightMode,
      darkTheme: darkMode,
      // themeMode: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeMode,
    );
  }
}

If thats the case later you can replace it with some StateManagement to avoid creating variables in your build method many times (Provider, Riverpo, Bloc, etc) or just StatefulWidgets.
Other way is that you can make your RouteConfig a singleton and returnRouter return your previous created instance, there are many ways, but TLDR: it's not GoRouter's fault, always avoid creating big objects with their own state in the build method.
Update 19.11.2024
I´ve found the reason why the app reloads. I´ve tried to add riverpod to fix the problem but the ChangeNotifier reloads the app. It´s cause of the themeMode option in the MaterialApp:
class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final appThemeMode = ref.watch(appThemeProvider);

    return MaterialApp.router(
      // General information
      title: "Construction Diary",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: RouteConfig.returnRouter(),
      // Theme management
      theme: lightMode,
      darkTheme: darkMode,
      themeMode: appThemeMode.mode,
      // themeMode: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeMode,
    );
  }
}

theme_provider.dart
final appThemeProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => ThemeProvider());

class ThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeMode mode = ThemeMode.system;

  void setLightTheme() {
    mode = ThemeMode.light;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setDarkTheme() {
    mode = ThemeMode.dark;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setSystemTheme() {
    mode = ThemeMode.system;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleTheme() {
    mode = _onToggleTheme(mode);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ThemeMode _onToggleTheme(ThemeMode themeMode) {
    switch(themeMode) {
      case ThemeMode.dark:
        return ThemeMode.light;
      case ThemeMode.light:
        return ThemeMode.dark;
      default:
        return ThemeMode.system;
    }
  }
}

Is there a way to update the themeMode property without reload the app? I need to add the watcher cause you can change the theme in the settings between light and dark theme.

I´ve added your code for test reason. But still got the "double" load. It looks like it´s a StreamBuilder inside the StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack. I´ve a authoration and that change will be checked over the StreamBuilder.

I don't see any StreamBuilder in your example, nor how a child widget can force to refresh the Materialapp, do you have any provider that can force to update MaterialApp.router?

You have to make your routerConfig a provider too, so when the theme updates the router doesn't rebuild, another thing you can do is pass a Key to your MaterialApp, const ValueKey('App') for example
